# get a reference of object from List of objects in c#

Tags: c#, reference

i want to get a reference from a list of objects on an object ,

so the reference  i want object type

i will explain in the following example

i have a method like

```
method (ref Foo foo)
{
//
}
```

and  i have a list of Foo

```
List<Foo> listFoo;
```

and i want to call this

```
method(ref listFoo[i])
```

so this return a reference of a listfoo and i want the reference of the foo number i in the list

thanks

Comment: i want the reference of the foo in the list not a reference of a listfoo

Comment: sounds kinda like homework---if so, please add the #homework tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the direct array reference; you cannot obtain that via a list. Not least, this is because the list is free to reassign the underlying array at any point - rendering your reference confusing at best.

If it was an array, the you could use the `method(ref arr[index])` approach you mention; but **only** with arrays.

Note: this trick is only useful in two scenarios:

- you want to **reassign** the value in the array
- you want to access a `struct` in-situ, without causing it to be copied

For most purposes, passing the **object reference** is fine, i.e.

```
Method(Foo foo); // Foo is a class
...
Method(list[i]); // pass the reference to the object, unrelated to the container
```